# doubleX(String someString) method should return Boolean based on whether input string contains consecutive 'x' characters

Tags: java, boolean

I'm very new to Java and I have this assignment for college. We have to:

Create a class called DoubleX with a static method called doubleX which takes a String as a parameter and returns a boolean value which will be true if the first 'x' in the string is immediately followed by another 'x' and false otherwise.

For example, in the string, "abcdxex", the first 'x' is immediately followed by an 'e', not an 'x' and therefore the method will return false. On the other hand, the string, "aaaxxaa" will cause the method to return true.

Your method will be called by another Java class as follows: (this is provided by my lecturer)

```
public class main
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
      boolean result = DoubleX.doublex("aaaxxaa");
      System.out.println(result);
   }
}
```

So far my code looks like:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DoubleX
{
     public static void main (String [] args);

     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

     System.out.print("Enter a phrase: ");

     String phrase = in.nextString();  

     }
}
```

I've been trying many options but nothing works.

Please help!

I've been working at it. Can anyone say if I'm on the right track? It seems to be working but it keeps telling me that there is an identifier problem with the last line `System.out.println(result);`

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DoubleX
{
     public static boolean doubleX (String [] args);
         Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Please enter a word: ");
         String name = in.next();
         result = DoubleX.doubleX(name);

     {
         if ("xx")
         System.out.println("True");
         else
         System.out.println("False"); 
     }

     System.out.println(result);
}
```

Comment: I think you need to take a step back and learn about java class, methods, and scope before you try writing code

Comment: Your teacher already gave you the `main` method. Why are you writing your own `main` method? You need to create a `static` method named `doublex` in your class `DoubleX`, that takes a `String` parameter and returns a `boolean`. See: [Defining Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)

Comment: Ok I have progressed to this:

import java.util.Scanner;

public class DoubleX
{
     public static void main (String [] args);
     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
     String name = in.next();
  
     {
         if ("xx")
         System.out.println("True");
         else
         System.out.println("False"); 
     }
     boolean result = name.doublex();
     System.out.println(result);
}

Comment: @Dervy Is `doublex` the same as `main`?

Comment: @Dervy you are no where near the solution. First you need to figure out how to define a static method, with a boolean return value, and a String argument. Figure that out, post that method signature, then we can help you from there

Answer (score 2):

Once you've got the input from the user (you did that quite nicely - and actually, that's not part of the assignment), it should be fairly simple to check if the string contains two Xes right behind each others (namely `"xx"`). There's at least two ways you can do this:

- **Simple:** By using the method [`String.contains(CharSequence)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains-java.lang.CharSequence-), which checks if a String contains another String
- **Overkill:** By using regular expressions to check if your String matches a pattern like `<any amount of arbitrary characters>xx<any amount of arbitrary characters>`

Only thing that's left to do is to define a `public static` method inside `DoubleX` with the name `doublex`, a `String` argument and a return type of `boolean` (see also: [@JamesWierzba's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33105426/doublex-boolean#comment54026443_33105426)).

Comment: Descriptive response that points OP in the right direction without doing all the legwork for him/her, well done.

Comment: @LanguidSquid You mean "descriptive response which tells OP the solution for the main problem, so he doesn't need to think about it", right?

Comment: @Tom Actually, I edited the question after the comment of LanguidSquid so that it also contains information about the last bit of information that wasn't added in my answer (the addition of the `doublex` method).

Comment: @Tom There is no doubt that OP would get more value out of doing independent research and working through the problem himself. While the answer does short-circuit the research, it still leaves the implementation up to the asker. Ultimately this is subjective, but I think the answer does more good than harm.

Comment: import java.util.Scanner;

public class DoubleX
{
     public static boolean doubleX (String [] args);
         Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Please enter a word: ");
         String name = in.next();
         result = DoubleX.doubleX(name);

     {
         if ("xx")
         System.out.println("True");
         else
         System.out.println("False"); 
     }

     System.out.println(result);
}

Am I getting any closer @flashdrive2049?

Comment: @Dervy You might want to start using an IDE (such as [Eclipse](https://eclipse.org/), [IndelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/specials/idea/idea.jsp) or [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/)) if you have trouble finding errors (which are pretty obvious, to be honest) in your code.